# Google maps android custom images

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

I have a specific problem with Google Maps for Android. I should be able to make Google Maps look like the map on this page www.bam.brno.cz, but I'm new to Goole Maps for Android so I don't know if there's a way to do it.

I don't have any of those map images, but i guess there should be a way to get it from the internet (like WMS or something). If I was eventually able to save them and use them offline that would be great, but if not and the app would have to use data connection, it's also ok.

I already got app with google maps, so the question is just about how to get the map images and replace default google maps images.
Also if that wouldn't be posible, I would like to know what other options I have(like if theres some other map images I can use and how)

PS: not sure how it's called correctly: map images/map tiles

EDIT: I don't care about the objects, I know how to do them. I don't know how to get the whole map, the tiles it's made from. I'm already familiar with markers and camera moving etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use **marker** for same.

You can try some thing like ..

```
m = myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(startLatLng.latitude, startLatLng.longitude))
        .title("Vivek Test"));

Here m is Marker;
and myMap is GoogleMap
```

Complete structure like this ..

```
myMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        //myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        myMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(startLatLng));
        myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20), 2000, null);

        m = myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(startLatLng.latitude, startLatLng.longitude))
        .title("Vivek Test"));
```

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: Yea but I didn't mean the "objects" on the map :) I meant this whole map. I mean how do I get the "tiles" of the map, not sure if it's called like that. Objects I'll add later.

Comment: You can use customized images too as well. my post is just for a reference

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one file holding a series of coordinates (Latitude, Longitude) of each of the colored lines.  Get those coordinates and use [Polylines](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline).  These should take care of the colored lines.  The grey dots would be [Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker) and these could be in the same file.  Assuming that GoogleMaps has similar places names, then with these two you ought to be able to reproduce the map.

Comment: Yea but I didn't mean the "objects" on the map :) I meant this whole map. I mean how do I get the "tiles" of the map, not sure if it's called like that. Objects I'll add later.